# get two columns in MySql and multiply results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

ok i have the following:

```
user id    meta
   2      _qty      3
   2      Weight    20
   1      _qty      1
   1      weight    30
```

I need to grab the user id column then multiply the qty by the weight giving me for user id 2= 60 and user id = 1 30...... 
I've tried the following but to no avail:

```
 $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT meta_value, SUM(_qty*weight) AS product_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta GROUP BY ($query_select_order_items)" );
```

where `($query_select_order_items)` is the user_id. 
how do i go about this?

Actual php I'm currently running:

```
/**
 * Returns all the orders made by the user
 *
 * @param int $user_id
 * @param string $status (completed|processing|canceled|on-hold etc)
 * @return array of order ids
 */
function fused_get_all_user_orders($user_id,$status='completed'){
    if(!$user_id)
        return false;

    $orders=array();//order ids

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'     => -1,
        'meta_key'        => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'      => $user_id,
        'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
        'post_status'     => 'publish',
       /* 'tax_query'=>array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  =>'shop_order_status',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     =>$status
                    )
        )  */
    );

    $posts=get_posts($args);
    //get the post ids as order ids
    $orders=wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' );

    return $orders; 
}
function fused_get_all_products_ordered_by_user($user_id=false){

 $orders=fused_get_all_user_orders($user_id);
 if(empty($orders))
   return false;

 $order_list='('.join(',', $orders).')';//let us make a list for query

 //so we have all the orders made by this user which was successfull

 //we need to find the products in these order and make sure they are downloadable

 // find all products in these order

 global $wpdb;
 $query_select_order_items="SELECT order_item_id as id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id IN {$order_list}";

 $query_select_product_ids="SELECT meta_value as product_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE meta_key=%s AND order_item_id IN ($query_select_order_items)";


 $products=$wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($query_select_product_ids,'weight'));

 $qty = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare($query_select_product_ids,'_qty'));


 return $products;
}
```

Where currently that $products on the end returns a list of weight's or if i set it to _qty it will return a list of the quantities ordered...
[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10138)

Update from strawberries answer:

```
"SELECT order_item_id, weight * quantity total FROM ( 
 SELECT order_item_id, 
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_qty' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) quantity , 
   MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weight' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) weight 
   FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta GROUP BY order_item_id) 
   WHERE  order_item_id  IN ($query_select_order_items) x;"
```

Comment: try this query `"select meta_value,_qty*weight from table_name group by ".$query_select_order_items`

Comment: Are you sure you have only one `_qty` and `weight` per user?

Comment: i will only ever have one _qty yes possibly more weights though...

I'll update my question with the actual snippet i am running

Comment: actually thats wrong each user_id  could and will have various _qty's and weights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(entity,attribute)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(2,'quantity',3),
(2,'weight',20),
(1,'quantity',1),
(1,'weight',30);

SELECT entity, weight * quantity total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT entity
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'quantity' THEN value END) quantity
            , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'weight' THEN value END) weight
         FROM my_table
        GROUP
           BY entity
     ) x;

+--------+-------+
| entity | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |    30 |
|      2 |    60 |
+--------+-------+
```

... or even just ...

```
SELECT entity 
     , ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG(value)))) total 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY entity;
+--------+-------+
| entity | total |
+--------+-------+
|      1 |    30 |
|      2 |    60 |
+--------+-------+
```

Adapting the first query to your fiddle might look like this...

```
SELECT order_item_id, weight * quantity total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT order_item_id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_qty' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) quantity
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weight' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) weight
         FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        GROUP
           BY order_item_id
     ) x;
```

...and the second might look like this...

```
SELECT order_item_id
     , ROUND(EXP(SUM(LOG(meta_value)))) total 
  FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
 WHERE meta_key IN('_qty','weight')
 GROUP 
    BY order_item_id;
```

... and adapting the first to your latest requirement...

```
SELECT i.order_item_id, weight * quantity total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT order_item_id 
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_qty' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) quantity
            , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weight' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) weight
         FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
        GROUP
           BY order_item_id 
     ) x
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items i
    ON i.order_item_id = x.order_item_id
 WHERE i.order_id IN(647,649,650);
```

Comment: tha kind sir is genius thank you..... 
DO you have any idea how i would combine this into it: "SELECT order_item_id as id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id IN {$order_list}"
where the order_list is the actual orders i need the ids from...

Comment: what is that end X for?

Comment: ok I tried above which kinda made sense i want to filter the whole thing to return only results matching the first sql query...
SELECT order_item_id as id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id IN {$order_list}

Where Order_lists is a comma spereated list of orders...

Comment: ok this works i think: 
    ( "SELECT order_item_id, weight * quantity total FROM ( SELECT order_item_id, MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_qty' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) quantity , MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'weight' THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) weight FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta GROUP BY order_item_id) x WHERE  order_item_id  IN ($query_select_order_items);");

Comment: why? I can not figure out what that X does do you have something i can read to explain it

Comment: it really doesn't explain why i need that X :*( I don't understand it...
It does work now though so screw it i suppose! Thank you yet again

Comment: It needs an x because "Every derived table must have its own alias". Anyway, see edit above

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.user_id, 
       SUM(A.meta_value * B.meta_value) 
FROM   t A INNER JOIN t B ON A.user_id = B.user_id 
WHERE  A.meta = 'weight'
   AND B.meta = '_qty'
GROUP BY 
       A.user_id
```

You can try it in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fe901/1/0)

Comment: OK I have no clue what I need to replace here so it works with my code.. where do i input $query_select_order_items

Comment: @vimes1984 I don't understand your comment. You can see from the fiddle what the query returns. I think you only need to change table name from t to yourTableName and then fetch results in php to get user_id and the computed field value. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query :

```
select tbl1.val*tbl2.val
from mytbl as tbl1,mytbl as tbl2
where tbl1.user_id=tbl2.user_id
and tbl2.meta='Weight'
and tbl1.meta='_qty'
```

Also i prepare [fiddle of it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860e6/11/0).

Comment: @vimes1984 which one is your desired table to do the operation?